# Sending a image to servlet in java how to get the image in servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am sending a image from android phone to server which is a servlet I am using the HttpClient and HttpPost for this and ByteArrayBody for storing the image before sending.

how do i extract the image from the post request in Servlet.

Here is my code for sending the post request

```
String postURL = //server url;

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postURL);

ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes,"file_name_ignored");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("source", bab);
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like [commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

There are examples in the Apache docs, and all over the web.

Comment: can you post an example for this

Comment: @user964428 Click on the link and look at the user guide, or one of the examples. If you just regurgitate what someone else posts, how will you diagnose/troubleshoot any problems?

Answer (score 2):

Servlet 3.0 has support for reading multipart data. [MutlipartConfig support in Servlet 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html)
If a servelt is annotated using @MutlipartConfig annotation, the container is responsible for making the Multipart parts available through

1. HttpServletRequest.getParts()
2. HttpServletRequest.getPart("name");

Answer (score 0):

use http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

```
private DiskFileItemFactory fif = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);

    if(!isMultipart)
        throw new ServletException("upload using multipart");

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fif);
    upload.setSizeMax(1024 * 1024 * 10 /* 10 mb */);
    List<FileItem> items;
    try {
        items = upload.parseRequest(req);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

    if(items == null || items.size() == 0)
        throw new ServletException("No items uploaded");

    FileItem item = items.get(0);
    // do something with file item...
}
```

Comment: but I am sending the image to the server so after getting it how can i use it to do some editing on it

Comment: I think that's another question :) but there's alot you can do: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/